# SSL Certifcate for Apache/Tomcat

Tags: ssl, apache2, tomcat6, cas, mod-jk

I followed this [tutorial](http://blog.samimakela.fi/blog/2011/07/19/grails-and-single-sign-on/) to create a ssl certificate for a CAS server, now I decided that I need to use a vhost using the mod_jk, so the certificate need to be set in the Apache vhost config file..

The problem that my certificate is a binary file and can't use it with Apache, anyone has an idea how to convert that certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution..
I set my OpenSSL certificate to Apache..
Then from my browser I export it to a binary file (DER).. After that I copied it to my server then I add it to the tomcat cacert file (as shown in the tutorial)..
Hope that'll help somebody else one day..